# Is it possible to play Playstation Network games on my phone without owning a Playstation system?

Tags: psn

I want to play the games I own on PSN on my Android. I had to sell my PS4. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If they are playable on Android, yes. If not, no. It's that straightforward.
Most of the games offered on PSN cannot be played on an Android device.

PSN is the Playstation Network, a gaming platform similar to Steam and Uplay. While they mainly distribute games for Playstation consoles, I'm sure some of them can be played on an Android device (whether through emulation or not).